# Add fit lines from an nlme model to a ggplot, and include confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, nlme

I've used nlme to model my data like this:

```
library(nlme)
my_model <- lme(metric ~ group * time, random = "~1 | tech_rep", na.action = "na.omit", data = my_data)
```

I then want to plot my data, but include fit lines from the nlme model. I gather from some posts that this can be done with `ggpredict` ([Extract prediction band from lme fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit)). I've managed to add the lines, but I'd also like the confidence interval to be displayed as a shared area around the line (as is default for `geom_smooth`). Setting `se = TRUE` doesn't seem to do anything.

```
ggpredict_data <- ggpredict(my_model, c("time", "group"), type = "re")
ggplot(ggpredict_data, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group, fill = group)) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, fullrange = TRUE) +
    geom_point(data = my_data,
               aes(x = time, y = metric, colour = group))
```

Can anyone help get the confidence interval working?

R, reading around, trying other posts

Comment: I'm linking to your other recent post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77498716/use-an-lme-model-with-a-random-effect-to-add-a-fit-line-to-a-ggplot. I think your chances of getting an answer to these two questions is likely higher if you place all this information into a single post, rather than into two separate ones. Someone who comes to this post won't have access to the data (`my_data`) and someone who goes to the other post won't see what you are trying with `ggplot`.